# Set "Content-Encoding" and "Accept-Encoding" headers to None

Tags: python, http, header, python-requests

is there any way to set "Accept-Encoding" and "Content-Encoding" headers to None in python requests library?

My headers are:

```
headers = {
    "Expect": "100-continue",
    "User-Agent": None,
    "Cookie": "Some cookies",
    "Accept": None,
    "Accept-Encoding": None,
    "Connection": None,
    "Content-Encoding": None
}
```

This is how it looks like in wireshark:

```
POST URL HTTP/1.1
Host: HOST
Accept-Encoding: identity
Cookie: Cookies
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Length: 0
Content-Encoding: deflate
```

How it MUST look like:

```
POST URL HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Expect: 100-continue
Host: HOST
Cookie: Cookies
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want the request to indicate that you don't want to process a content-coding in the response, sending "Accept-Encoding: identity" is correct.

Comment: Ye, i know that. I'm just trying to create an identical request. I’ve wrote what the request should look like, and I’m trying to achieve it.

Comment: can you please upload the call to `requests` and how you send the request ?

Comment: @ddor254 Simply requests.post(url, headers=headers). Actually here is an issue on github might help. Looks like i have to use urllib3 instead of requests https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2234